# type arguments do not conform to trait Subtractable's type parameter bounds

Tags: scala

After upgrading to Scala 2.12, I am having a weird compilation issue of this code:

```
val c = Map("a" -> Set[Map[String, String]](), "b" -> Map[String, String]())
```

It is throwing this exception:

```
Error:(19, 7) type arguments [?,Iterable[Equals] with String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] => Any with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[_ >: String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] <: Object, Iterable[Equals] with String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] => Any with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[_ >: String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] <: Object, Iterable[Equals] with String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] => Any with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[_ >: String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] <: Object, Equals]]{def seq: Iterable[Equals] with String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] => Any with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[_ >: String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] <: Object, Equals]}]{def seq: Iterable[Equals] with String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] => Any with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[_ >: String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] <: Object, Iterable[Equals] with String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] => Any with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[_ >: String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] <: Object, Equals]]{def seq: Iterable[Equals] with String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] => Any with scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[_ >: String with scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] <: Object, Equals]}}] do not conform to trait Subtractable's type parameter bounds [A,+Repr <: scala.collection.generic.Subtractable[A,Repr]]
```

Comment: Do you intend to have one of the values a `Set` and the other `Map`?

Comment: And what did that code achieve before updating to 2.12?

Comment: Yes, the 1st is a Set and the 2nd is a Map

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug. You could post it in [bug tracker](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues) if analog is absent.

As workaround try to append values to map.

```
scala> val c = Map.empty[String,Iterable[Any]] + ("a" -> Set[Map[String, String]]()) + ("b" -> Map[S
tring, String]())
c: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Iterable[Any]] = Map(a -> Set(), b -> Map())
```